# What are the relation properties of  = {(, ) | gcd(, ) = 1}

Tags: elementary-number-theory, relations

I am guessing that it is reflexive since it relates to itself $gcd(x,y)=gcd(x,y)$

But I can't think of a way to picture the relation to find if it's transitive and symmetric.

Comment: If x is greater than 1, does x relate to itself? I'd guess no since the gcd would be x that is greater than 1. Symmetric is easier to show as the order doesn't matter so $xRy=yRx$.

Comment: @JBKing how would you show that it doesn't relates to itself, since there are two variables?

Comment: Symmetry and non-reflexivity directly imply non-transitivity, since $x R y$ and $y R x$ should imply $x R x$, but this is not true by non-symmetry. So the relation is only reflexive.

Comment: Also it isn't transitive.  Consider 2R3,3R4 and 2R4

Comment: Consider $x=y=3$ and see that the relation doesn't hold in this case.

Comment: @QthePlatypus when you say $2R3$, do you mean $x=2$ and $y=3$?

Comment: @PhoxKiD Yes 2R3 means x=2 and y=3.

Comment: @QthePlatypus oic, so $2R3$ means that they satisfy condition

Comment: Yes for for something to be transitive $ xRy \wedge yRz \implies xRz$ which the above is a counter example of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've mixed up "reflexive" which asserts every element is related to itself $xRx$ (and is not true here) with "symmetric" which says all relations are two-way, $xRy \iff yRx$ (which is true).

Because the relation is symmetric but not reflexive, we immediately know that it is not transitive, since $xRy$ and $yRx$ do not lead to $xRx$.

As for picturing the relation, in plain words it says $x$ and $y$ are coprime, or have no common factors greater than $1$. Since $x$ definitely has a common factor with itself, that eliminates reflexivity easily, and the rest follows as above.

Comment: Is it by definition that if the relation is symmetric and not reflexive it must be not transitive?

Comment: It's not by definition. @Joffan proved it in his answer.

Comment: Unless it's empty, that immediately follows